# Operate on 1D arrays in gnuplot

Tags: arrays, gnuplot

How to do something equivalent to this:

```
In: A = [ 1 2 3 ]
In: B = 2 * A
In: B
Out: [ 2 4 6 ]
```

This method gets part of the way:

```
In: do for [i in "1 2 3"] { print 2*i }
Out:
2
4
6
```

But I want to return another list/array that can be used in further operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, using space-delimited words is the only way to simulate arrays. So you must format the output again as a string in which the single entries are separated by spaces:

```
out = ''
do for [i in "1 2 3"] { 
    out = out . sprintf('%d ', 2*i)
}

print sprintf('%d entries: %s', words(out), out)
```

This prints

> 3 entries: 2 4 6

If using floats, you must use e.g. '%f' to format the output:

```
out = ''
do for [i in "1.1 2.2 3.3"] { 
    out = out . sprintf('%f ', 2*i)
}

print sprintf('%d entries: %s', words(out), out)
```

`words` counts the words in a string, and you can use `word` to extract a certain word from the string (starting from `1`):

```
print word(out, 2)
```

> 4